# I need help ending a loop that updates a 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays

There is one part of this code that I need help with. This code is calculating the steady-state temperature distribution on a plate. The prompt I was given states:

> You should continue to iterate until no cell in the array changes more than 0.1 degree, calculating the temperature for all interior cells on each iteration. Your program should monitor the largest change for any cell in the array in order to determine when to stop reiterating.

And I'm stuck! I'm currently using a while loop to get the right answers but I just can't figure out how to get it to do what I was asked in the prompt. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 20;
const double HEAT = 100;
const double EDGES = 0;
const int SURROUNDING = 4;
const int STABLE = .1;

// Initializes the first array
void begining_plate ( double plate[][SIZE]) {}


// Calculates one ideration of the steady-state distribution
double average_temp_calc(double plate[][SIZE], int a, int b) {}

// Prints the array
void print_plate( double plate[][SIZE]) {

// Exports the array to a .csv file
bool send_plate_info(double plate[][SIZE])


int main() {


    // Part 1 - Initialize and Print 2D Array
    cout << "Here is the initial heat: " << endl;
    double plate[SIZE][SIZE];
    begining_plate(plate);
    print_plate(plate);


    // Part 2 - Update Elements once
    double plate_saved[SIZE][SIZE];

    cout << "\nHere is the first run of the averaged plate.\n";
    for (int a = 0; a < SIZE; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < SIZE; b++) {
            if (a != 0 && a != SIZE - 1 && b != 0 && b != SIZE - 1) {
                plate_saved[a][b] = plate[a][b];
                plate[a][b] = average_temp_calc(plate, a, b);
            }
            else {
                plate_saved[a][b] = plate[a][b];
                plate[a][b] = plate[a][b];
            }
        }
    }
    print_plate(plate);
    cout << endl << endl;

    // Part 3 - Repeat update until stalbe

   ******* HERE IS THE PART I NEED HELP WITH **********

    int count = 0;
    int stable = 150;
    while (count < stable) {
        for (int a = 0; a < SIZE; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < SIZE; b++) {
                if (a != 0 && a != SIZE - 1 && b != 0 && b != SIZE - 1) {
                    plate_saved[a][b] = plate[a][b];
                    plate[a][b] = average_temp_calc(plate, a, b);
                }
                else {
                    plate_saved[a][b] = plate[a][b];
                    plate[a][b] = plate[a][b];
                }
            }
        }
    count++;
}
// Part 4 - Using Excel to Display Results

        if (send_plate_info(plate))
        {
            cout << "File wrote correctly\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The file did not write!\n";
        }



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I saw your comment that you solved the additional issue by yourself, congrats :-)

Answer (score 1):

The counting should be done on the number of unstable points rather than on the number of loops:

```
for (int a = 0; a < SIZE; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < SIZE; b++) 
    {
        if (a != 0 && a != SIZE - 1 && b != 0 && b != SIZE - 1) {
            plate_saved[a][b] = plate[a][b];
            plate[a][b] = average_temp_calc(plate, a, b);
        }
        else {
            plate_saved[a][b] = plate[a][b];
            plate[a][b] = plate[a][b];
        }
        if ( abs(plate_saved[a][b]-plate[a][b]) > STABLE )
            ++count;
    }
```

This way you count only the unstable points, and you stop when there aren't any:

```
do
{...}
while (count>0);
```

**EDIT**

Be careful that the counter of unstable points must be reset at the beginning of each iteration, so that the solution should look like this:

```
do
{
    count = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < SIZE; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < SIZE; b++) 
        {
            double plate_saved = plate[a][b];
            // Compute new value of plate[a][b]
            if ( fabs(plate_saved-plate[a][b]) > STABLE )
                ++count;
        }
}
while (count>0);
```

Comment: So I tried your suggestion, and played around with it a little bit, but everytime it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a life saver!